# Rails 3.2.11 encoding issue as it now turns single quotes into html entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently upgraded from: gem 'rails', '3.2.5' to gem 'rails', '3.2.11'.

I now see the following issue:

**Rails View:**

```
MagicThing.set({uuid : <%= "'"+Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{current_user.id.to_s}#{SITE_CONFIG['key']}")+"'" %>});
```

With Rails 3.2.5 this would output correctly as:

```
MagicThing.set({uuid : '6cea6a412094b5633f2011df59bc86b0'});
```

But now after updating to Rails 3.2.11:

```
MagicThing.set({uuid : &#x27;6cea6a412094b5633f2011df59bc86b0&#x27;});
```

Any idea what happened to cause the single quotes to be turned into html entities. And based on that the right way to resolve? Thanks

Comment: As a quick fix, I simply added raw in the front and it outputted correctly but I'm curious how this randomly happened in the latest rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md#rails-328-aug-9-2012), it looks like Rails 3.2.8 changed this:

> ERB::Util.html_escape now escapes single quotes